# how can i check if an element is visible in php?

Tags: php, html

i have a couple of variables that i want to save or not save to a database depending on whether or not i have set them as hidden/visible in a javascript function, i have searched for a while but cant find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's absolutely impossible since PHP runs on the server while JavaScript and CSS are client-side.

The only thing you can do is checking if the element is visible using JavaScript and sending that data to your PHP script, e.g. via a hidden `<input>` field.

Comment: is there any code that i can use to completely remove an element in the javascript based on its id?

Comment: Yes, with `elem` being the element: `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function deleteAnswer(button)
 {
 button.parentNode.removeChild(button); }
 </script>       for some reason this doesnt work, i saw the exact same code that you posted somewhere else and already tried it

Answer (score 3):

You can also have this alternative. NOTE that the page has to refresh before this take effect (i.e. before PHP has knowledge of what was going on)

```
//Your JavaScript
function setHidden()
{

   document.getElementById('elementForVar1').visibility = 'hidden';

   //use this to indicate field/variable is hidden. PHP will use this later
   document.getElementById('elementForVar1HiddenField').value = 1;
}
```

declare hidden fields in your form to store the states of the variables

```
<form name="xxx">
    <input type="hidden" id="elementForVar1HiddenField" name="elementForVar1HiddenField" value="0" />
</form>
```

Your javascript simply set the value of the hidden field to 1 indicating var1 is hidden

```
<?php
  if($_POST['elementForVar1HiddenField'] == 1)
     //variable was hidden

?>
```